# Successfully registered user message in the View before inserting it into the database ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this user registration Action in my Controller but I would like the View to show a message like: ***"User successfully registered"*** before proceeding to login. What would be the best way to implement it? I'd appreciate your help

```
// REGISTRO USUARIO
public ActionResult RegistroUsuario()
{
    return View();
}

// REGISTRO USUARIO [POST]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RegistroUsuario([Bind(Include = "IDUSUARIO,TIPO,NOMBRE,APELLIDO,DNI,EMAIL,USUARIO,CLAVE,SEXO,FECHANAC, DISTRITO")] TB_Usuarios tB_Usuarios)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.TB_Usuarios.Add(tB_Usuarios);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
    }

    return View(tB_Usuarios);
}
```

Comment: Return a view which displays the message and has a link to the login action. If required, add Javascript to that view to load the login action after a fixed time.

Comment: You need to use `Ajax` if you want to show the message on `RegistroUsuario` view and then do the redirect. Otherwise return a view which shows this message and then apply a redirect using javascript on that view after a certain time interval.